# jedis transaction success response

Tags: java, redis, jedis

What is jedis transaction execution success response? It seems that jedis will return 1 for success response. If the transaction includes two operations, will my following codes work?

```
 List<Object> ret = jedisAdapter.exec(tx, jedis);
 return ret.size() == 2 && (Long) ret.get(0) > 0 && (Long) ret.get(1) > 0;
```

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: it really depends on what is `jedisAdapter` and what it does in `exec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to get every operation result with get() method in a try catch. Getting result of an unsuccessful operation throws an exception. Redis transactions are not like database transactions. They only provide atomic operations, when one of the operations fail others wont roll back.